# $_GET no coge espacios en blanco

Tags: php

A la hora de generar el url, tengo

```
<a class="anadir_a_cesta" href="index.php?accio=añadir_producto_cesta&producto_id=<?php echo $detalle['id']?>&precio=<?php echo $detalle['Precio']?>&nombre=<?php echo $detalle['nom']?>">Añadir producto a la cesta</a>
```

Después, cuando hago `$_GET["nombre"]` no me coge los espacios en blanco, es decir, si tengo SAMSUNG GALAXY, solo me coge SAMSUNG. Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
Gracias.

Comment: Los espacios en blanco en las **URL** han de ser enviados como **%20**. Ejemplo: `index.php?producto=samsung%20galaxy`, ya que estas, entre otras cosas, no pueden contenerlos porque rompes la cadena.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero si lo tengo almacenado en una variable, ¿cómo lo harias?

Comment: Haciendo un `str_replace(" ", "%20", $mi_variable)`.

Answer (score 2):

La función `rawurlencode()` devuelve la cadena con los reemplazos pertinentes para una URL:

```
<?php echo rawurlencode($detalle['nom'])?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para construir direcciones que contienen parámetros que van a ser usados en direcciones (url) que van a lanzar solicitudes al servidor, en las que las respuestas serán procesadas usando $_GET() es conveniente recurrir al método `encodeURIComponent(valor)`.

Dichas direcciones deben construirse así:

```
<script lang="javascript">
var enlace = path_a_la_pag + '?nombrevariable_1=' + encodeURIComponent(valor1)
    + '&nombrevariable_2=' + encodeURIComponent(valor2); //... etc
</script>
```

Nota: los valores `valor1, valor2, ...` debe ser asignados leyendo en los atributos de los elementos presentes en el documento.

Comment: ¿En javascript?

Comment: @Sal Si!. Hice los cambios necesarios agregando etiquetas para que el lenguaje sea explícito.